# Есть ли нативный способ разрезать картинку на javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Интересует есть ли способ разрезать картинку (например из одной фото вырезать 2 разных квадрата) на **чистом javascript**`e **на стороне клиента**. Понимаю, что есть библиотеки, но мне нужен именно нативный js. Какие технологии и методы поизучать, каков может быть алгоритм. Благодарю.

P.S. Картинку или несколько итоговых картинок буду отправлять на сервер. Вырезать необходимо на фронте.

P.P.S.

Реализовала на canvas. Тут пример http://in-web.h1n.ru/projects/photowalls/ .
Only front, only js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите исходники библиотек по работе с изображениями.

[Вот](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/master/croppie.js), например, js-cropper, в исходниках видно, что изображение сначала переводиться в canvas, затем canvas редактируем, затем сохраняем canvas в файл.

Соответственно, изучаем работу с canvas и FileAPI (для сохранения в файл).

Простой пример обрезания картинки:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    // draw cropped image
    var sourceX = 150;
    var sourceY = 0;
    var sourceWidth = 150;
    var sourceHeight = 150;
    var destWidth = sourceWidth;
    var destHeight = sourceHeight;
    var destX = canvas.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
    var destY = canvas.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

Взято [отсюда](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/).

Answer (score 3):

Сниппет, в котором картинка разделяется на левую и правую часть, может пригодится кому-нибудь

```js
function putImagePartIntoImg(context, imgDivId, x, y, width, height) {
  let imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);
  let canvasPart = document.createElement('canvas');
  let contextPart = canvasPart.getContext('2d');
  canvasPart.width = width;
  canvasPart.height = height;
  contextPart.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  document.getElementById(imgDivId).src = canvasPart.toDataURL();
}

let image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = '';
image.onload = function () {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  document.getElementById('source').src = canvas.toDataURL();
  putImagePartIntoImg(context, 'left', 0, 0, image.width / 2, image.height);
  putImagePartIntoImg(context, 'right', image.width / 2, 0, image.width / 2, image.height);
};
image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/n1iS0S6s.png';
```

```html
<p>Исходное изображение:</p>
<img id="source">
<p>Левая часть:</p>
<img id="left">
<p>Правая часть:</p>
<img id="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

Опять же Вы не написали, а что вы с картинкой хотите делать, после того, как разрежете ее.

Допустим Вы хотите просто показать 2 половинки.

Тогда задача очень проста и делается средствами css. Скажем есть картинка с иконками (например 2 штуки одна под другой). А нужно вывести их в разных местах.

Делаем при помощи background-position (как бы начинаем рисовать на половину картинки выше):

```
<style>
#foto-1 {
  background-image: url(photo.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#foto-2 {
  background-image: url(photo.png);
  background-position: 0 -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div id="foto-1"></div>
...
<div id="foto-2"></div>
```

Все эти свойства (background-position, width и т.д.) вместо css можно устанавливать при помощи javascript. Там нет ничего сложного.

Если же хотите сохранить на на сервере, то смотрите решение от AirCrisp. Хотя я бы передал изображение полностью и разрезал бы сервером, так больше форматов изображения можно поддержать и не быть завязанным на браузер.